# How to load and store values of the preferences screen into SQLite DB?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

just added a Preference-Screen into my app. I want to load and store the given values into my sqlite db. I do not know how to solve that, because I dont know how to access the fields in the oncreate of my method, they have no android:id field but an android:key

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="Preferences">

  <PreferenceCategory
     android:title="@string/program_options">

     <CheckBoxPreference         
       android:key="pref_opt1"
       android:title="@string/autoLogin"
       android:summary="@string/autoLoginDescription"
       android:defaultValue="true"
       />

  </PreferenceCategory>

  <PreferenceCategory
     android:title="@string/program_informations">

    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_type"
        android:title="Type"
        android:summary="Select item from array"
        android:entries="@array/types"
        android:entryValues="@array/types_values"
        android:defaultValue="1"
        />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_text"
        android:title="Input text"
        android:summary="Tap to enter some text"
        android:dialogTitle="Enter text"
    />

  </PreferenceCategory>

  <Preference
    android:title="Visit us"
    android:summary="SRS-Management GmbH">

    <intent
      android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
      android:data="http://paperdynamix.de/" />

  </Preference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

and my Activity where i want to access the fields

```
package de.srs.android.pdixuploader.activies;

import de.srs.android.pdixuploader.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.CheckBox;


public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    private CheckBox autoLogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //here I want to read and prefill the values of the fields 

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
    }                   
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to "prefill" the values since Android handels all the needed values by itself (first time the default values will be used).

In order to get the values just use the following code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
// For example
Boolean pref_opt1 = sp.getBoolean("pref_opt1", true)
// generally
// sp.get[TYPE]("KEY", STANDARD-VALUE);
```

Comment: will these preferences be stored inside the app, so after a reboot, the settings are as before? Or do I have to persist these values in the db and load them at the start of my app?

Comment: No, they are stored persistent "inside" your app. Imagine the `SharedPreferences` as a text-file with read/write access. So actually there is no need to to put these values in your database or recover them.